# Extract a PascalCase string and number from an underscore separated string

Tags: vba, outlook

The given string is formatted FirstnameLastname_ABC_11111_500
I need to extract Firstname, Lastname, and 500 while ignoring the rest (ABC, random numbers, and underscores), into a string formatted: "Firstname Lastname / 500"

Not sure what is the best way to approach this in a VBA script.

Comment: Seems like a good job for the `Split` function - it being in PascalCase is irrelevant - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: Oh to also separate the first and last name? I suppose you could parse the first split result character by character and check it for upper/lower case. What if it's KenO'Brian?

Comment: @braX parse character by character using the Split function?

Comment: no, split it by underscore first, that gives you an array, and the first item in the array will have the first/last name - that you can then parse character by character to try and find where the capital letter in the middle is, assuming there is only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this will work fairly decently. I've added some safety nets, but this could be improved a bit further. I've coded it as a function, but, of course, you may just add the block to your code as you need it.

This code splits (`VBA.Split`) the input into pieces using the `_` as separator, then parses the first part character by character, detecting uppercase letters and adding spaces before them. My full name consists of 6 words, so I have done it so this code is compatible with as many words as needed. ;)

Finally, the code detects if there actually were more segments in the input string, and adds the last one to the result string.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function stringExtractor(givenString As String) As String
    
    If VBA.Len(givenString) > 0 Then    ' If the user enters an empty string, this prevents execution errors
    
        Dim stringParts() As String
        Dim finalResult As String
        Dim fullName As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim currentChar As String
        Dim lastPart As String
        Dim partCount As Integer
        
        stringParts = VBA.Split(givenString, "_")   ' Gets the original string split into its components, and loaded into stringParts
        
        fullName = stringParts(0)   ' Gets the name part into a variable of its own
        finalResult = ""
        i = 1
        
        Do Until i > VBA.Len(fullName)  ' Loops through all the name, to start loading it into the finalResult
        
            currentChar = VBA.Mid(fullName, i, 1)
            
            If currentChar = VBA.UCase(currentChar) And VBA.Len(finalResult) <> 0 Then ' If we find an uppercase character and finalResult is not empty (this is not the first word)
                finalResult = finalResult & " " & currentChar                           ' we are entering a new word, and we have to enter both the found character and a blank space
            Else
                finalResult = finalResult & currentChar                                ' Else, we're in the same word as before, and we only have to add the found character.
            End If
            
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        
        partCount = UBound(stringParts) ' Get how many parts has the string (zero-based)
        
        If partCount > 0 Then   ' If there was something else than just the name
            lastPart = stringParts(partCount)   ' Get the last bit of the string
            
            finalResult = finalResult & " / " & lastPart    ' And attach it to the end result
        End If
        
    End If
    
    stringExtractor = finalResult   ' This will return the full name, separating the words with spaces and (if there is one) the number at the end of the original string.
        
End Function
```

If you want the code to ONLY give a result if there is a name segment and a "final number" segment, `If` clause should be moved like so.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function stringExtractor(givenString As String) As String
    
    If VBA.Len(givenString) > 0 Then    ' If the user enters an empty string, this prevents execution errors
    
        Dim stringParts() As String
        Dim finalResult As String
        Dim fullName As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim currentChar As String
        Dim lastPart As String
        Dim partCount As Integer
        
        stringParts = VBA.Split(givenString, "_")   ' Gets the original string split into its components, and loaded into stringParts
        
        If partCount > 0 Then   ' If there was something else than just the name
            fullName = stringParts(0)   ' Gets the name part into a variable of its own
            finalResult = ""
            i = 1
            
            Do Until i > VBA.Len(fullName)  ' Loops through all the name, to start loading it into the finalResult
            
                currentChar = VBA.Mid(fullName, i, 1)
                
                If currentChar = VBA.UCase(currentChar) And VBA.Len(finalResult) <> 0 Then ' If we find an uppercase character and finalResult is not empty (this is not the first word)
                    finalResult = finalResult & " " & currentChar                           ' we are entering a new word, and we have to enter both the found character and a blank space
                Else
                    finalResult = finalResult & currentChar                                ' Else, we're in the same word as before, and we only have to add the found character.
                End If
                
                i = i + 1
            Loop
            
            partCount = UBound(stringParts) ' Get how many parts has the string (zero-based)
            lastPart = stringParts(partCount)   ' Get the last bit of the string
            
            finalResult = finalResult & " / " & lastPart    ' And attach it to the end result
            
        End If
        
    End If
    
    stringExtractor = finalResult   ' This will return the full name, separating the words with spaces and (if there is one) the number at the end of the original string.
        
End Function
```

Hope this is good enough for your question, don't hesitate to ask me for further detail.